# In Puppet, what is the difference between 'include' and 'class'?

Tags: puppet

I can either write

```
include '::ntp'
```

or I can write

```
class { '::ntp':}
```

What is the difference between them, or do I need both?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are differences, here are two big ones:

Using `include` allows multiple declarations of a class.  The `class` declaration can only be used once or you'll see a duplicate resource declaration error.

`include` will use external data, e.g. hiera, for parameters.  Declaring `class` allows you to specify the parameters.

See https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#the-include-function

Answer (score -1):

**Include** is to tell puppet to apply the class "ntp" to a node and **class** is to declare the class, the behavior of this class (like ensure file, package, user etc...)

Comment: class *defines* a class, while include *declares* (i.e. uses) it.